INFO [SequenceIdentityGenerator] - <HHH000067: Disallowing insert statement comment for select-identity due to Oracle driver bug>
I have enabled Hibernate logs in my application
spring.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

Now I am able to see hibernate queries and select statements except for insert queries.
When I changed following logger properties to see detailed logs
<logger name="com.db.nwd.hibernate" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="com.db.nwd.zk.utils.HibernateSessionExecutionListener" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="TRACE"/>

I am getting one info message as below
INFO [SequenceIdentityGenerator] - <HHH000067: Disallowing insert statement comment for select-identity due to Oracle driver bug>

Is this the issue which causing insert messages to print in logs or this is just info message? Please help.
Also it would be great help if anyone able to tell me why I am not able to see insert queries in Hibernate logs.
Hibernate version - 5.3.2-final
Spring version - 5.3.34
database - Oracle
version - com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:19.20.0.0
Tried changing log level from info to trace.

There is a bug in the Oracle driver that causes queries with comments to be executed incorrectly. To avoid this problem, Hibernate automatically disables adding comments and reports it in the log.
INFO [SequenceIdentityGenerator] - <HHH000067: Disallowing insert statement comment for select-identity due to Oracle driver bug>

You may not see insert queries in the log because of this bug.
Since the bug occurs when using the GenerationType.IDENTITY identifier generation strategy, you may want to try switching to GenerationType.SEQUENCE to resolve the issue.
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
public Long id;

You may also want to try upgrading your JDBC driver.
To log query parameters you can use the org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind logger at the TRACE level. Also, perhaps the org.hibernate.SQL logger at the DEBUG level will help you see the insert queries.
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind" level="TRACE" />


Hi @Andrey,
Thanks for reply.
Unfortunately I cannot change from triggered to sequence identity generator. I'll check if I can upgrade driver.
Also I wanted to know is there any way(in debug) to check which insert statements are getting executed with what parameters ?(may be silly question, I can always check in db but in my case due to rollback for Junit test I am unable to check in db).

@Sanat To log query parameters you can use the org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind logger at the TRACE level. Also, perhaps the org.hibernate.SQL logger at the DEBUG level will help you see the insert queries.
